# Initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed on fresh 20.04 install

Tags: boot, 20.04

I couldn't boot because of something with bluetooth so I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 using the wipe disk and install option. But now I get the error in the title followed by "gave up waiting for root file system device", "ALERT! /dev/sda2 does not exist" and busybox. What should I do to enter Ubuntu?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Which drive did you say it should install on? Looks like you've installed it on a drive that  is not present anymore... Easiest: Get yourself an USB stick an reinstall your OS. But that will remove all your private data..

Comment: @kanehekili as I thought I made clear, I just did that, using the "wipe disk and install" option. Then the error showed up after I tried to boot

Comment: This is strange. If you take an USB stick, start the "live" image and start installing it, it will ask you at the beginning where to install "grub" That place should be (obviously) not sda2 but the drive that is in your hardware.. (like sda1 -most likely)

Comment: You mean usb stick with Ubuntu? It never asked me anything about grub

Comment: Yes, I mean that stick. At one place you will be asked **where** to install the system. That`s the "grub" part...

Comment: II did not find any image to provide you with more infos. But you need to to "overwrite" anything you've installed previously

Comment: Ok thanks, I fixed it by installing with manual partitioning

Comment: Interesting. What were the default values? Usually Ubiquity (the installer) will give you the option to overwrite everything ...

Comment: @kanehekili I think the default was EFI+root, and I did EFI root swap home, if that's what you asking about